# When should I use a custom Manager versus a custom QuerySet in Django?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-managers

In Django, custom managers are a great way to organize reusable query logic. The [Django documentation on **Custom managers**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) says:

> There are two reasons you might want to customize a `Manager`: to add extra `Manager` methods, and/or to modify the initial `QuerySet` the `Manager` returns.

However, [it goes on to describe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods) how custom `QuerySet` classes can also be created, and that these can be made accessible directly from the data model as a manager using `QuerySet.as_manager()`:

> The `Manager` instance created by `QuerySet.as_manager()` will be virtually identical to the `PersonManager` from the previous example.

It seems like there is a lot of flexibility in how one could organize their logic between custom `Manager` and/or custom `QuerySet` classes. What are the principles by which I should decide when to use one versus the other?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Mainly to allow for easy composition of queries. Generally if you want to be able perform some operation on an existing queryset in a chain of queryset calls you can use a `QuerySet`.

For example, say you have an `Image` model that has a `width`, `height` fields:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    width = ...  # Width in pixels
    height = ... # Height in pixels
```

you could write some custom `QuerySet` methods:

```
class ImageQuerySet(models.QuerySet): 
    def landscapes(self):
        return self.filter(width__gte=models.F('height'))

    def portraits(self):
        return self.filter(width__lte=models.F('height'))

    def small(self):
        return self.filter(width__lte=1200)

    def large(self):
        return self.filter(width__gte=1200)

class ImageManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ImageQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
```

now you can easily create dynamic querysets:

```
Image.objects.all().portraits().small()
Image.objects.all().large().portraits()
```

Logically, these functions should be concerned primarily with partitioning or redefining of existing querysets of the queryset's model. For situations where you aren't operating on existing querysets, you don't want to return a queryset at all, or you might have to perform some related logic that doesn't involve this particular model, than a model manager it better suited.

Comment: From Django 1.7 you can just set `objects` to `YourCustomQuerySet.as_manager()`. Then you only need to create the query set class. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add `objects = ImageManager()` to the `Image` model in order for this to work?

Comment: @Brodan pretty sure, yes

Comment: So the major usage is Custom QuerySet。

use Custom Manager previously only because it is middle in Model/QuerySet？

Answer (score 63):

I kept reteaching myself what is a `Manager` vs a `QuerySet` so, I thought I better write here, so make it easier next time I wonder.

A `Manager` is the class that is attached to your model and returns a `QuerySet` instance,  `objects` being the default manager. Most manager methods, ex. `all()`, `filter()` return queryset instances.

In more detail, when you do `YourModel.objects.filter(..)` you get a queryset instance. When you want to filter it again, you can chain another `.filter(..)` method only because it is also available on the `QuerySet` class too. That is what you want.. have your methods on both the manager and the queryset it returns.

If `filter` was not also a manager method, you would have to do `YourModel.objects.all()` to get the queryset, and *then* add the `filter` method(s) from there.

To make things easy, Django defines a `as_manager()` method on the QuerySet class which turns it into a, well.., a manager [[docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods). Therefore, you define all your custom methods on your queryset, and turn it into a manager, and attach to your model, so you can call it the first time (as a manager method) and chain it as many times as you want (as queryset methods).

Writing this answer, I wondered if there are any manager methods shipped with Django that aren't queryset methods, and the first that came to my mind was the `get_or_create` method since it does not seem to need a queryset. But guess what? that also turned out to be defined on the `QuerySet` class.

Long story short, you almost always want to write QuerySet methods and have them on the manager too via the `as_manager()`.

Comment: Can you provide Django application that uses that approach (define custom `QuerySet` and use it as a manager with `.as_manager()`)? I can't find any custom `QuerySet` in my project dependency codes. Instead, I found pretty much apps that define their custom `Manager` (such as: `allauth.account`, `allauth.socialaccount`, `django.contrib.admin`, `django.contrib.auth`, `registration` of `django-registration-redux`, etc)

Comment: When use `QuerySet.as_manager()`，the majority QuerySet's method would be copy to Manager。 

So these methods is both QuerySet's method and Manager's method

Comment: @hashlash I think the Custom Manager with name is used to distinct various data usage, and Custom QuerySet is DRY

Comment: @hashash All of those apps likely were created long before you could use `QuerySet.as_manager`.

Comment: I keep looking for this comment and has been helpful ever since